# Displaying data of particular link clicked

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am creating a spring mvc estore web application.A jsp page here named "showproducts.jsp" renders the all the products from the database in a table.There is a column named "Additional info" here.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-success">
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.productname}</td>
            <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdtdetails">Additional info</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I want that href to a particular product goes to "pdtdetails" page and there show all the details of only **this** specific product when clicked on.I am using the below code in my "pdtdetails.jsp" but as expected it displays details and their respective data for all the products and NOT the only one clicked.

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
    <tr>
        productname:${product.productname}<br> 
        manufacturer:${product.manufacturer}<br>
        category:${product.category}<br>
        description:${product.description}<br> 
        units:${product.units}<br>
        price:${product.price}<br>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

How should I go about in bringing out this behaviour?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-success">
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.productname}</td>
            <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdtdetails?id=${product.id}">Additional info</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tobdy>
</table>
```

Then in your details page, fetch the selected item from query param and show only it:

```
<c:out value="${param['id']}"></c:out>
```

You would, of course, need to implement a method to fetch the entity from the database.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the solution.It works just as required.@RequestParam in the controller was also added for supplying the id to the DAO layer.